# Why does changing password in System Preferences work when it doesn't through Terminal?

Tags: terminal, system-settings

My question might also be put, "What does System Preferences -> Users & Accounts do to change a user's password that I'm missing in the command line?"

The desktop is joined to both OD and AD directories. I can change my own user's auth with

```
$ passwd <uname>
... (update pwd through dialog) ...
$ dscl . -passwd /Users/<uname>
... (update through dialog) ...
```

However, I can't use it for other users. I just get a dscl error -14009 (eDSUnknownNodeName). It doesn't matter if I use a full admin account, sudo -s, or anything.

What else might I try? I really want to be able to do this through terminal so I can write a bash for loop to change the passwords more easily.

Comment: `dscl .` is for the local OS X directory.  Unless all the users have been logged in at one point to the Mac you're on, you'll have to specify the path to the directory you're editing, e.g. `dscl /Active Directory/All Domains` for AD and `dscl /LDAPv3/<directory path>` for OD.

Comment: No, the account is local, and I CAN change the password with dscl . /Users/<user>, but only if I am that user. However, I CAN also change the password for a different user but only if I go through the System Preferences gui. Why?

Comment: I created a local test account and changed the password without issue.  I then tried to change the password while misspelling the account name and received the same error.  Are the local accounts you're trying to change actuall "mobile" accounts from a directory login?

Comment: No, not mobile accounts. But I found that 10.6.8 machines don't have the issue while 10.7.5 do. Anyway, I just worked around it, but I am still interested in knowing exactly what System Preferences does behind the scenes when it deletes a user. Or doesn't do for that matter, because I found that I needed to to run a dscl . -delete /Users/<uname> anyway to clear out some cruft it left.

Comment: Just did some testing on mavericks. Your commands work fine, if you do the following: `passwd username` (old password: "password", new password: "password1"), then `dscl . -passwd /Users/username` (new password: "password1", old password: "password1"). Note that the old password and the new password are the same in the `dscl` command, but not the `passwd` command.